# restkit and RKManagedObjectSearchEngine

Tags: restkit

I'm looking for a sample code using RKManagedObjectSearchEngine.
Class are available but not test case and no documentation is available on the API
I have posted this question on the forum but no support :(

Any help is welcome...

Answer (score 0):

The RestKit managed object search engine has been substantially overhauled and completely documented. Please see: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/tree/development/Code/Search